# Is there a term for tablature with numerals placed between the lines?

Tags: notation, terminology, tablature

In most of tablature notation for fretted instruments, each line represents a string and the numerals, representing the frets where to stop the string, are printed *on* the respective lines.

However, for 4-stringed instruments there exists literature [1, see picture] with the tablature consisting of five lines and the numerals printed *in between* those lines.
In this case a string is represented by a gap between two lines.

Is there nomenclature distinguishing between those two types of tablature?

[image: Tablature with numerals between lines. From Mel Bay's Complete Jethro Burns Mandolin Book.]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmteZ.png) Jehtro Burns and Ken Edison, Mel Bay's Complete Jethro Burns Mandolin Book, Mel Bay Publications, Inc., ISBN 1-56222-663-0 (1993)

Comment: It's still tab.  Not sure there is a different name.  I have seen this for guitar as well.

Comment: I'm not able to answer definitively, but I would just refer to it as Tab for mandolin as opposed to Tab for guitar.

Answer (score 2):

Unlikely.

Your opening sentence is confirmed here:  "In tablature, the horizontal lines represent the strings of the instrument: six strings for guitar and dobro, four for mandolin and ukulele, five for banjo."  This [notation guide](https://pegheadnation.com/string-school/music-notation-guide/) uses a 6-, 5-, or 4-line staff, with a clef "TAB."

Your picture's omission of the unusual clef and usage of the common 5-line staff both suggest that this is a publisher's shortcut, not yet deserving the dignity of its own name.